# Anyone know how to convert Flash Actionscript 2.0 game into HTML5? Since Swiffy Flash Conversion is no longer available

Tags: html

currently I have been searching on internet how to convert flash swf to html5 but what i get is the conversion is mainly for Actionscript 3.0, then how about Actionscript 2.0?

Plus, when i googled Swiffy Flash Conversion, the page mentioned that it no longer available.

Does anyone know is there other way to convert Actionscript 2.0 games to HTML5 mobile app? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

If there was such a thing then there would be less old flash content. You can only convert simple stuff because the way flash and html5 canvas work are completely different, so your best bet is to rewrite the game without any converter. It was clear for years that flash support is running out in browsers.